# Java toTitleCase function

Tags: java, string

I have this Java function that's supposed to convert the string `s` to title case.  It should return a *copy* of `s` to the caller, leaving `s` preserved.

Currently, `rv` ends up as an empty string.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
private static String titleCase(String s) {
        String rv = new String();
        StringTokenizer strtok = new StringTokenizer(s);
        // handle the potential null error: (should really output a runtime warning here)
        if(s == null) return null;
        while(strtok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String word = strtok.nextToken();
            String firstLetter = word.substring(0,1);
            String restOfWord = word.substring(1);
            rv.concat(firstLetter.toUpperCase() + restOfWord.toLowerCase());
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

Comment: If you are doing the null check (or throwing the exception), you should be doing that first, before _anything_ else in the method; why create the `StringTokenizer` if it isn't going to be used?  (although the optimizer may be smart enough to reorder that anyways, it would read better for maintenance programmers anyways)

Comment: Because I'm a C programmer.  I just can't break the habit of putting variable declarations before code.  Thanks for pointing it out, though, I should re-order it really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings being immutable in Java, once you have declared rv as "" (= new String()) it won't change unless you allocate a new String to it.
You can either replace the concat line by:

```
rv = rv.concat(firstLetter.toUpperCase() + restOfWord.toLowerCase());
```

Or better, use a StringBuilder instead of a String (not tested):

```
StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder();
// [...]
rv.append(firstLetter.toUpperCase()).append(restOfWord.toLowerCase());
// [...]
return rv.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I had to modify it slightly to put back the spaces as well but I would've had to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`WordUtils.capitalize`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) or [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: If you could edit in an example of how to use it, I'll consider switching the accepted answer.  As it stands, this isn't as useful to me as the other answer.  Thanks for your input, though :)

Comment: There are some examples on the linked javadoc. Have you checked it? :-)

Comment: Yes I did check the javadoc and it only presented me with an extra concern - would this solution not require an extra library to be included/depended upon?  It seems like a bit of a minute problem to add a dependency for, so I'd rather roll my own solution.